# Check toggle state

Tags: jquery

I want to check a toggle state. When I check the console log of my browser, the visible value is true and doesn't change to false.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

---

```
<html> 
<head>
<script src='~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#divUpdateForm').click(function () {

                $('#divUpdateContent').slideToggle();

                console.log($('#divUpdateContent').is(":visible"));

            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divUpdateForm" runat="server" class="panel" >Update panel state</div>

<div id="divUpdateContent" runat="server">
... my content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it before you slide the element, during the slide, the element will always be visible:

```
$(function () {
    $('#divUpdateForm').click(function () {
        var v = $('#divUpdateContent').is(":visible")


        $('#divUpdateContent').slideToggle();

        // note that the variable v is also accessible here ?
        console.log(v)
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N83az/)

Comment: But how can I test .is(":visible") after .slideToggle() function

Comment: If you're going to wait until the slide has completed, and then do something, you do it in the callback, like in the answer from palash, but that will wait the 0.6 seconds it takes to slide the element before the check is done etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the toggle state after the toggle is completed in the `callback` function like:

```
$('#divUpdateForm').click(function () {

    $('#divUpdateContent').slideToggle(function () {

        // Animation complete.
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            console.log($(this).is(":visible"));
        } else {
            console.log($(this).is(":visible"));
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ezfc/)